# How to update azure data factory pipeline and push changes from the repo?

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I created a pipeline manully in azure data factory which contains a databricks notebook and already synch with the github repo. I download the repo locally to make further changes. I also created github actions pipeline for the CICD integraion
below is the code structure

```
- .github
- Adf_root
- factory
- linkedService
- pipeline
  - publish_config.json
```

below contains publish_config.json

```
{
    "name": "Test_DF_Pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Test_Notebook",
                "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:0:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "notebookPath": "/test_notebook_path"
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "DF_Linked_Service",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-10-21T06:31:10Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

now if i need to make changes in the notebook with updated code base how we supposed to make changes locally as we do normally in the CICD process?

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Tl;dr you have to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, In order to edit your notebook, you need to integrate databricks [repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/#supported-git-providers) with github

So you can **first** Link Databricks with GitHub by creating a repo from your Databricks workspace folder and enter the URL of your GitHub repository and the GitHub Personal Access Token

**Then** you can easily pull/push the workspace changes from/to github using the workspace folder in the repo.

you can also add it to your [CI/CD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/ci-cd-techniques-with-repos) workflows  to automatically update the Databricks repo after each github merge
To do so, you need to use the [repo API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/repos) endpoint that will be called by Git automation. And Github Actions can do that.